# Vuetify v-select não funciona

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Estou testando o mesmo código de exemplo do site oficial porém por algum motivo não quer mostrar as options de jeito nenhum

A view tá assim

```
   <template>
      <div class="about">
        <v-select
          :items="items"
          label="Standard"
        ></v-select>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    export default {
      data: () => ({
        items: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Fizz', 'Buzz'],
      }),
    }
  </script>
```

e o main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

O ./plugins/vuetify.js está assim

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framework';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
});
```

não fiz nenhuma alteração nele

Comment: Como está configurado o `./plugins/vuetify.js`?

Comment: Adicionei ali pra você ver

Comment: Opa, tem como mostrar como está seu componente App.vue? Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Com certeza vc já resolveu esse problema, mas se outros tiverem essa dúvida fica aqui a resposta com um exemplo simples.

```html
'<v-select 
  :items="ufs" 
   label="UF:" 
   item-text="nome" 
   item-value="sigla"
>
</v-select>'
```

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "select-uf",
  data: () => ({
    ufs: [
      { nome: "Acre", sigla: "AC" },
      { nome: "Alagoas", sigla: "AL" },
      { nome: "Amapá", sigla: "AP" },
      { nome: "Amazonas", sigla: "AM" },
      { nome: "Bahia", sigla: "BA" },
      { nome: "Ceará", sigla: "CE" },
      { nome: "Distrito Federal", sigla: "DF" },
      { nome: "Espírito Santo", sigla: "ES" },
      { nome: "Goiás", sigla: "GO" },
      { nome: "Maranhão", sigla: "MA" },
      { nome: "Mato Grosso", sigla: "MT" },
      { nome: "Mato Grosso do Sul", sigla: "MS" },
      { nome: "Minas Gerais", sigla: "MG" },
      { nome: "Pará", sigla: "PA" },
      { nome: "Paraíba", sigla: "PB" },
      { nome: "Paraná", sigla: "PR" },
      { nome: "Pernambuco", sigla: "PE" },
      { nome: "Piauí", sigla: "PI" },
      { nome: "Rio de Janeiro", sigla: "RJ" },
      { nome: "Rio Grande do Norte", sigla: "RN" },
      { nome: "Rio Grande do Sul", sigla: "RS" },
      { nome: "Rondônia", sigla: "RO" },
      { nome: "Roraima", sigla: "RR" },
      { nome: "Santa Catarina", sigla: "SC" },
      { nome: "São Paulo", sigla: "SP" },
      { nome: "Sergipe", sigla: "SE" },
      { nome: "Tocantins", sigla: "TO" },
    ],
  }),
};
</script>
```